# Wrong sorted array.Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the following javascript array:

```
a=[0, "b", 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 9, 8, "A", "a", 11010]
```

Now I want to sort it and I do it like this

```
a.sort()
```

But then I get the following:

```
[0, 1, 11010, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, "A", "a", "b"]
```

Which I think is wrong because 11010 is greater than 2 and it should be after 2.
Also even if I do the following:

```
a.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
```

I get the following:

```
[0, "b", 11010, 2, 3, 4, 1, 8, 9, "A", "a", 5]
```

Can someone explain me why this is happening?Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - Sort Letter Number Combination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019731/javascript-sort-letter-number-combination)

Comment: What is your goal-ordering from the sort operation, and why are both strings and numbers in your array?

Comment: A [quick read from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) explains why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array has both numbers and strings. What you need to do is supply a compare function.

```
a = [0, "b", 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 9, 8, "A", "a", 11010]
a.sort(function(c1, c2) {
    if(typeof c1 === "number" && typeof c2 == "number") {
        return c1 - c2;
    } else {    
        return (c1 + "").localeCompare(c2);
    }
 );
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, when sorting, JavaScript treats all the array elements as strings by default.

JavaScript is not type-safe, like Haskell or Java. This means that you can perform all sorts of crazy actions like adding numbers and strings, or comparing strings to numbers without throwing an error.

[UTF-8 Character Code Table](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_basic_latin.asp)

As you can see in this table, **1** gets a value of 49, which is less than the value of 97 for a lower case **a**

"1" gets placed before "10110" for the same reason that "a" gets sorted before "apple"

---

[This video](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) covers a lot of the highly unexpected default patterns of JavaScript that result from dissimilar type operations.

Comment: *"since you include string elements"* even without string values all elements would be treated as strings.

Comment: Yea, that was his first answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at how array.sort works at this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

If you don't provide your own sorting function, then

> "elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing
>   strings in Unicode code point order."

As a string, 11010 comes before 2. You haven't provided a sort function, so the sort method is using the default behavior.

This is why you're seeing the behavior you've noted.